# Is "Steal my money if you can" acceptable in formal English?

Tags: formality

> Steal my money if you can.

Is this a correct sentence to use in writing, or is it more appropriate to use in  spoken English?
I was involved in a conversation using English and they said my grammar is not good enough.

Comment: I edited your question to fix, mainly, many spelling mistakes. Please note that using capitals is not optional in English. If you feel I changed the meaning of your question, feel free to edit it or roll back my edit :)

Comment: I am puzzled by this sentence, which does not seem to be something which anybody would ordinarily utter in either speech or writing. Does it perhaps have some idiomatic meaning in your own language? Please tell us what exactly you are trying to communicate.

Answer (score 3):

That sentence is grammatically correct. It is a challenge to the other person:

> "Steal my money if you think you are able to."

Comment: Hahah thank u a lot.i like the example u made tho:)